# page load without refresh and clear to memory for scripts

Tags: javascript

I am developing an MVC web project. I clicked the button and then load the page without the refresh. So far okay but my script codes are working 2 times when I click the button again. My problem is explaining to step by step:

1- I click the X button and then load the X.cshtml without the page refresh into the #currentPage element. There are x.js in X.cshtml

2- x.js script codes are working.

3- I click the Y button and then load the Y.cshtml without the page refresh into the #currentPage element. There are X.cshtml in Y.cshtml

4- x.js script codes are working 2 times.

5- I click the X button again, however, x.js script codes are working 3 times.

[A sample simple project](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/hO8J3uj44ovuK4t2?preview)

I think I need to remove the variables,functions etc. from memory right?

How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Load your scripts separately and not with HTML. Make sure you do not bind events multiple times.

Comment: I added the simple project, I am sure do not bind events multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that in the x.js an on-click listener is defined. Each time that you load the script a new listener is put on the button. Before loading the x.js you should remove the click listeners from the button `$('#button').off('click');`

Comment: Hm, thank you so much for your reply. Yes, it's useful however I think it looks a little difficult to manage for big and relational structures. Is there another way to solve the problem?

Comment: I think the best solution is to prevent the js file to be loaded more than once. There is a solution on https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/10/11/preventing-javascript-files-from-loading-multiple-times/.